# Selecting a range from table to which given number belongs

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have the following table:

[image: Please see Image]

Now what I want to do is find out which range a given number (suppose 4) belongs. And pick the corresponding `Trans_Charges` and `Handling_Charges`.

Any ideas how to do it using asp.net? I"m a newbie and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Is this MSSQL? MySql? something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unfortunate that the pole height range is stored that way. It makes for some ugly SQL. You need to use substring approach to extract out the low and high range then do a BETWEEN.
Assuming you are using MSSQL:

```
DECLARE @nbr INT;
SET @nbr = 4;
SELECT Trans_Charges, Handling_Charges
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE @nbr BETWEEN CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Pole_Height_Range,1,(CHARINDEX('-', Pole_Height_Range) - 1))) AND 
    CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Pole_Height_Range,(CHARINDEX('-', Pole_Height_Range) + 1), LEN(Pole_Height_Range)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Trans_Charges, Handling_Charges
  FROM (SELECT Trans_Charges,
               Handling_Charges,
               CONVERT (
                  INT,
                  substring (Pole_Height_Range,
                                        1,
                                        INSTR (Pole_Height_Range, "-") - 1))
                  AS min_height,
               substring (Pole_Height_Range,
                                     INSTR (Pole_Height_Range, "-"),
                                     len (Pole_Height_Range))
                  ) as max_height from tbl where Pole_Height_Range is not null)
where 4<=max_height and 4>=min_height
```